# Data CD for audiobooks?

Tags: audio, itunes, compact-disc

I'm trying to burn my .mb4-audiobook files to a CD. I was impressed by the compression-rate (10 hours of audiobook within 150MB?!). The problem now is, that I cannot burn it as an audio CD as these allow only about 80 minutes of audio (audiobook is about +10 hours).

I burned them as a data CD now. It works, but, of course, the downside of a data CD is, that not every player (e.g. car, stereo) can play data CDs.

What can I do? I don't want to waste 100 CDs on such a simple problem ... is there any way to burn an audio CD? I mean, just regarding the filesize this shouldn't be a problem, shouldn't it? Why is an audio CD only able to play up to 80 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of burning as audio CD try Mp3 CD. Most players can play them and I tunes can still handle it. That is main draw back to the mb4 format and why I dont use it!

Answer (score 0):

An audio CD is based upon length of the tracks. So, you have 80 minutes regardless of any file size at burn time - EG if you have 2 tracks, both lasted exactly 70 minutes and one of the tracks was 1MB and the other was 1GB, both would burn to an audio CD and both would last 70 minutes. Although for the record, if you managed to compress the same file from 1GB to 1MB although both fit, the quality will still be recorded meaning the 1GB version would sound great, the 1MB would probably sound terrible!

The only answer is to buy an FM trasmitter which can read SD cards (may be cheaper than buying CD's), or a new CD player which can read the DATA cds.

Comment: how can one save 1GB on a CD that says 700MB?

Comment: Because you're not saving data per-se, you're saving audio content where the length of the song / track (in minutes/seconds) is what counts. If you were saving data (pictures or music to be played on a DATA reading player, like a computer, then you're right, it couldn't).

Comment: okay, thank you!

We decided now to burn the audiobook anyway (even though it may not be best for environment ;) ).

Do you know how iTunes is gonna handle this? If I burn this .m4b-file (too large of course), is it just gonna cut after 80 minutes or is it good enough to cut at the end of a chapter or something? How would you do that?

Comment: Typically, these type of programs (as I don't know ITunes myself) will sum up the total length of all files, and then work out how many 80 minute discs are required. As you start the burn process, it will have already segregated the tracks per CD. This may not be desirable as you may get audio books starting half way through a CD

Comment: So what would you suggest? Is there a better program to burn the CDs, that take chapters in account somehow?

Comment: I think it depends on the quantity. If it were me, I would create folders on my desktop for each disc. Drag them into iTunes to see how long they are, as soon as they're as close to 80 mins as possible (and under 80 mins) then create a copy on the desktop. Repeat until all tracks are done. this way, you can control which goes on each disc. There could be a software to help, but I don't know of it

Comment: The problem is that I have only .m4b-files, which are large (up to 10h) ...

Comment: Then this won't be possible, if each file (track) is greater than 80 minutes. You will need to break each track down into smaller parts, there is software which exists (I don't know any names) which can detect 'chapters' and split files accordingly. [This may be of help](http://mp3.about.com/od/essentialsoftware/tp/best_mp3_file_splitters.htm)

Comment: I have used Audacity, it will take a while to get it done, but, unless you want your tracks to be 80 minutes long, I suggest having chapters any way, so user can 'skip' to the chapter they want to continue from if their stereo forgets where they were or the CD was removed from the player.

Comment: And lasty this may be automatic. http://www.totalrecorder.com/splitting&tagging_files.htm